# How to prevent a function from being called multiple times on Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, swift, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I have this function set up on Cloud Code that is called twice sometimes thrice, although I intend to have it run once. It is called through a Swift function.

***Cloud Code***

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    stripe.customers.create({ email: request.params.useremail }).then(function(customer) {
        user.set("cusToken", customer.id);
    return user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    }).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Customer created");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.error(err);
    });
});
```

***Swift***

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customer", withParameters: ["useremail": self.userEmailAdressTextField.text ?? ""], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            })
```

Comment: Could you set a global variable when the function is processing, then unset it once it is done?  Then the first line of the function checks it and just returns if it is set, otherwise allows the function to continue.

Comment: @big_water Thank you for your response. I am a bit confused to be honest. What variable should I make global?

Comment: can you show some of the code that is calling this CloudCode function?

Comment: @big_water I added it to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Code function running twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524450/cloud-code-function-running-twice)